# Recommended Cisco storm-control broadcast and multicast threshold value for user PC

Tags: switch, cisco-catalyst, multicast, broadcast, storm-control

What is the recommended storm-control threshold value of broadcast and multicast on Cisco IOS catalyst switches for ports connected to users?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this article](http://www.netcraftsmen.com/resource/protecting-a-cisco-catalyst-6500-switch-against-layer-2-loops/) helpful:

> This article presents the steps I took to develop a solution to
>   protect the Catalyst 6500 in the presence of a Layer 2 loop. These
>   steps include the following:
>
> How to simulate of a Layer 2 loop
>
> How to monitor the control plane traffic
>
> Control plane policing
>
> Storm control
>
> Hardware rate limiting
>
> Design recommendations